# Эксклюзивный селектор CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Я работаю над страницей, где выбранный элемент в списке не имеет данного класса. Примерно так:

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">not selected</li>
  <li class="a b">selected</li>
  <li class="a">not selected</li>
</ul>
```

Я хотел бы определить селектор CSS, чтобы захватить узел `li` на странице, имеющей **только** класс `a`.
Неудивительно, что следующего утверждения недостаточно:

`document.querySelectorAll('li.a')`

Потому что он возвращает **все** узлы `li`, имеющие класс `a`.

Есть ли идеи, как выполнить такой сценарий?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Exclusive CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52557181/7394871) от участника  [@Alberto De Caro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083946/alberto-de-caro).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52557181/7394871

Comment: Как на счет `.a:not(.b)`?

Comment: @ДавидМанжула нормально, публикуйте работающий ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".a:not(.b)"))
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">not selected</li>
  <li class="a b">selected</li>
  <li class="a ">not selected</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Несмотря на кажущуюся очевидность этого ответа, всё-таки в соседнем ответе правильно подмечено про пробел, который остаётся, когда управляют классами из скриптов. Возможно, что уже исправили, но раньше точно такое было - добавил класс, убрал класс, а пробел оставался. Тогда такая связка селекторов не прошла бы.

Comment: @UModeL, селектор никак не связан с пробелами, в отличие от соседнего ответа. Покажи пример, на котором он не работает, если считаешь, что такой существует. И про пробелы - это совершенно не баг. Что в коде написано, то и получается.

Answer (score 4):

- В таком случае вы можете рассмотреть такой селектор атрибутов:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li[class="a"]').length)
```

```css
li[class="a"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">Выберите меня</li>
  <li class="a b c d more classes">Не выбирай меня</li>
  <li class="a b">Не выбирай меня</li>
  <li class="a">Выберите меня</li>
</ul>
```

- Просто обратите внимание на лишнее пространство:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li[class="a"]').length)
```

```css
li[class="a"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a ">Обратите внимание на это !!</li>
  <li class="a b">Не выбирай меня</li>
  <li class="a">Выберите меня</li>
</ul>
```

- Но поскольку вы используете JS, вы можете использовать `trim()`,
  чтобы избавиться от лишних пробелов:

```js
var elem=document.querySelectorAll('li');
for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++)
  elem[i].className=elem[i].className.trim();

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li[class="a"]').length)
```

```css
li[class="a"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a ">Обратите внимание на это!!</li>
  <li class="a b">Не выбирай меня</li>
  <li class="a">Выберите меня</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557233/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Классы уже давно меняют через classList, а не через className.